# In Lancer, where does the second "r" in "corpro-states" come from?

Tags: lore, lancer-rpg

For some reason, in *Lancer*, "corporate states" are abbreviated as "corp**r**o-states" instead of seemingly more natural "corpo-states".

Is the reason for that extra "r" known?

Comment: can you provide a couple page notes where it is corpro as opposed to corpo?

Comment: @Trish The word "corpro-state" appears on pages 126, 344, 348, 354, among others. Plus every single instance of "Smith-Shimano Corpro" in the book (over 60).

Comment: Maybe to avoid (or help) confusion with "copro"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because that's how corporate is pronounced (by me)

In short, I pronounce "corporate" as "core-prit" and not "core-poor-it". I don't know if everyone else does, since I've never paid attention to it, but I assume so. Perhaps that's a quirk of American English, but if so, presumably it's a quirk the writers shared.

If "corporate" is pronounced "core-prit," the shortening to "core-pro" is obvious (because "core-per" is odd, and everyone knows "corporate" has 2 os in it), and "core-po" would sound unnatural. On the other hand, even if it's pronounced "core-poor-it," the long o of "core-po" doesn't appear anywhere, so there's no reason to end with it - the o is basically a finishing vowel in both cases.

Also, corpro sounds snappier than corpo. Corpo, for me, sounds vaguely similar to corpulent, corpse, corpuscle and so on - all the words that start with corp and then end smoothly. Corpro is clearly distinguished from those, though if corpro-states is a derogatory term that's an argument in the opposite direction, especially since corpulent could easily apply.

Caveat: I've never even heard of Lancer, and so this is entirely a guess. On the other hand, it seems completely reasonable, and I doubt the rules would have any information on it. If I'm wrong... I'd love to see an answer based on the book. Perhaps Lancer has a bunch of little anecdotes, one of which contains a hint.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for in the book, but if you'd like to take a peek yourself, download the "free version" of the core book, which has all the introductory setting material from the front but is missing some of the deeper-dive setting material in the back: https://massif-press.itch.io/corebook-pdf-free

Comment: The art is fantastic, its worth a look just for that.

Comment: _Lancer_ is an excellent system, too.

Comment: Can confirm:  Some Americans will pronounce it "corpret" (that e should really be a schwa) and some will more precisely articulate all three syllables.  This is somewhat determined by regional accent, but even aside from that it's a function of how quickly or carefully a given person is speaking.